# Mouse with macros

Tags: mice

I hope this is the right spot to post. Im looking for a mouse like the logitech g302 in size and weight but with more macro keys. Do you have any ideas. I really like the g302 but it does not have enough macro keys. I use palm grip mainly. Im having trouble finding mice similar but for small hands. Ill be using it for a laptop and desktop so it would be great if it could be wired and wireless, but i know im getting into high price range asking for that so its cool if it doesnt. Please move this to the appropriate spot if this isnt. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I dont really want to spend more than 40-50 if i dont have to. I understand that it wont be the best mouse ever too. I just want to find one like the g302 with more buttons.

Comment: How many macro keys is enough? You could get a MMO centric mouse with 9 for example

Comment: More than 6 or more, excluding left and right click

Comment: I meant 6 or more

Answer (score -2):

Does the Roccat Tyon suits you?
A bit more expensive that what you've asked (~65€) but:

- 16 buttons
- From my experience, it's a really good mouse

http://www.roccat.org/fr-FR/Products/Gaming-Mice/Tyon/